# MediaWiki "no text in this page" with special characters in search field

Tags: url, mediawiki

We're upgrading from MediaWiki 1.13.2 -> 1.15.4. One of the issues we see is that when a page is searched for which in which the page name contains special characters, the page cannot be found.

Specifically, if the page is called **A&B** (A ampersand B) and I type **A** in the search field it will (correctly) show me **A&B** as a search suggest. When I select A&B I will go to a page marked **A** with this message:

> There is currently no text in this
>   page. You can search for this page
>   title in other pages, search the
>   related logs, or edit this page.

The URL will be correct: `<fullURL>/A%26B`

(This is also seen if I press *Random page* several times until I come across this.)

Anyone know how this can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Our `LocalSettings.php` had:

> $wgArticlePath = "${wgScriptPath}/$1";

I removed this line which then gave `title=` in the URL. I resolved this by adding:

> $wgUsePathInfo = true;

to `LocalSettings.php`

The only disadvantage is that `/index.php` is added to **all** the URLs. If anyone can solve that I'll gladly vote up! =:-)

Answer (score 1):

See the the **[Short URL](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL#Ampersand_.28.26.29_problem)** article on MediaWiki.org for some details that may help you including a few options for fixing it.

Comment: I Googled for ages but did not find this, thanks. I won't investigate further because I now have a working solution but this is useful info.